# Prepend string to messages of a range of git commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have a range of commits in my local git repository with the following messages:

```
Added source.h
Broken link fixed
Corrected unit test
Deleted deprecated algorithm
...
```

Before pushing them to the server, I would like to prepend ticket information to every commit message:

```
Ticket #9999 (1): Added source.h
Ticket #9999 (2): Broken link fixed
Ticket #9999 (3): Corrected unit test
Ticket #9999 (4): Deleted deprecated algorithm
...
```

Of course I could `git rebase` and `reword` every sigle commit, but I would like to automate the process as it's so repetitive.

I think it should somehow be possible with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), but the environment variables only provide
`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL, GIT_AUTHOR_DATE, GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, but not the message.

How can I access and automatically manipulate the commit messages?

**EDIT:** Note that the ticket number is always the same, but the number in the brackets is incremented successively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [hint from Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57525435/9167702) to use the `--msg-filter` option of [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), the full solution is:

If the commit range is `XXX..HEAD`, the bracketed number can be expressed with `git rev-list --count XXX..$GIT_COMIIT`.
Thus the messages can be transformed with `sed`:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
    i=`git rev-list --count XXX..$GIT_COMIIT`
    sed "1s/^/Ticket #9999 ($i): /"
    ' XXX..HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have logic for which ticket number to attach to each message, you would use the `--msg-filter` option of `filter-branch`.  See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch for details.

Comment: Using this I can prepend the ticket and #, but how do I successively increment the bracketed number?

Comment: @Tobi - I see that you're commenting on a second question that you edited into my answer.  As you see, I've rolled my answer back, as my answer was explicitly not intended to be an answer to that second question.  Sorry, but editing answers to ask follow-up isn't how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a githook for this exact functionality.

This code will prepend the branch name to the commit message:

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e ^* | tr -d ' *')
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ]; then
    echo "[$BRANCH_NAME] $(cat $1)" > $1
fi
```

If you want to get this working you first need to make an executable in the .git/hooks directory in your repo and call it `commit-msg`.

See this link for the source above: https://gist.github.com/bartoszmajsak/1396344/97081e76ab275f5fe526347908503febd1340495

Also another useful link about git hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks